# /etc/hosts file add edit and deletes using root user OR admin users

Tags: 16.04, command-line, networking, hosts, xterm

i have 60+ plus workstation running ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04

is there any tools or command that can i automatically add edit or delete hosts file in location /etc/hosts

for example:

pc-1
pc-2
pc-3

i want to add to their /etc/hosts for example an ip"1.1.1.1" how can i write it to terminal with just one command or one tools then when i hit enter it automatically adds to the 3 pc's. please help me or any suggestions about it...any help please by this method it can helps me to saves time a lot "process like API's"

because now im using two procedures 
1.1 by 1 go to station by station and edits the etc/hosts file...
2.remotely edits 1 by 1 by terminal

please help me....Thank you

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/puppet.html

Comment: @Rinzwind ? Don't get what you want to say

Comment: Puppet lets you alter systems that are in your network. That includes editing hosts file and updating their system from your machine. And lots more.

Comment: If you need a possible method: create on your machine sub directories matching your network addresse. Example IP 10.0.,2.1 then 'mkdir -p 10/0/2/[1-255]' and then use a script to walk this path to fetch all the hosts. Use 'sed' to alter the files and a second script to upload them.

Comment: Would that work for you?